# cannot convert value of type input nserror? ( aka input optional nserror to expected argument type ()

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, exception, xcode7

i update my Xcode now i have Xcode 7 , when it converted my codes i have this NSError problem, any idea how to fix it?

```
    if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {



        restaurant = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Restaurant", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Restaurant
        restaurant.name = nameTextField.text
        restaurant.type = typeTextFiedl.text
        restaurant.location = locationTextField.text
        restaurant.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image!)
        restaurant.isVisited = isVisted
        //restaurant.isVisited = NSNumber.convertFromBooleanLiteral(isVisited)

        var e: NSError?
        if managedObjectContext.save(&e) != true {
            print("insert error: \(e!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
    }
```

Comment: The entire error handling model changed with Swift 2 to "throwing errors". Is is documented in the Swift books.

Comment: i am new in swift so can you please just tell me how to correct it?

Comment: The referenced question already has an answer which shows how to do it.

Comment: if I could do that i would  not asking a question